# How to change the template used on a BrowserView depending on a parameter

Tags: plone

We have a view named `@@export` that expects an optional parameter `version` so you can call it like `@@export?version=3`.

As each version can be completely different one from each other, doing a gigantic template to keep all versions together would be a nightmare to maintain, so we thought that on the `__call__` method of the BrowserView we could dynamically change the template used, something like this:

```
class MyView(BrowserView):
    template = ViewPageTemplateFile('default_template.pt')

    def __call__(self):
        version = self.request.get('version', None)
        if version is not None:
        self.template = ViewPageTemplateFile('export-{0}.pt'.format(version))
        return self.template()
```

Turns out that it does not work. But actually trying on a debugging console we made it work like this:

```
class MyView(BrowserView):
    template = ViewPageTemplateFile('default_template.pt')

    def __call__(self):
        version = self.request.get('version', None)
        if version is not None:
            self.template = ViewPageTemplateFile('export-{0}.pt'.format(version))
            return self.template(self)
        return self.template()
```

Notice the return on the if code path.

Is there another way to dynamically change the template being used? Because this `return self.template(self)` does not seem really sane to me.

Comment: Is registering a view for each option and remodeling the `export` view into just doing a redirect feasible in your use-case?

Comment: Any error, or does it just not use the new assigned template?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz, if possible we would like to avoid it as this export view needs to be processed by another server and I don't know how good is their HTTP library.

Comment: @Mathias yes, from the top of my head an AttributeError that the parameter it needs on ``self.template()`` did not had the attribute request (and no, self.request was not working, so just self it does work, why?!)

Comment: But `template` is a class level attribute? Maybe there's some strange behavior overriding this.

Why not simply define `template = ViewPageTemplateFile('export-{0}.pt'.format(version))` and then `return template()`

Comment: @keul I already tried that and does not work, but yes, the class has a template attribute, I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You could try to put the logic into the **init** method rather than the **call** method but I would recommend to create separate pages for each purpose and traverse them from a master page. It is easy to share meta information (interface, permission) for pages via zcml:pages.